# Can you std::bit_cast to a std::array to obtain the bytes of an object?

Tags: c++, c++20, type-punning, bit-cast

In his recent talk [“Type punning in modern C++”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_qzMpk-22cc) Timur Doumler [said](https://youtu.be/_qzMpk-22cc?t=2755) that `std::bit_cast` cannot be used to bit cast a `float` into an `unsigned char[4]` because C-style arrays cannot be returned from a function. We should either use `std::memcpy` or wait until C++23 (or later) when something like `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(&f)[i]` will become well defined.

In C++20, can we use an `std::array` with `std::bit_cast`,

```
float f = /* some value */;
auto bits = std::bit_cast<std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(float)>>(f);
```

instead of a C-style array to get bytes of a `float`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, this works on all major compilers, and as far as I can tell from looking at the standard, it is portable and guaranteed to work.

First of all, `std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(float)>` is guaranteed to be an aggregate (https://eel.is/c++draft/array#overview-2). From this follows that it holds exactly a `sizeof(float)` number of `char`s inside (typically as a `char[]`, although afaics the standard doesn't mandate this particular implementation - but it does say the elements must be contiguous) and cannot have any additional non-static members.

It is therefore trivially copyable, and its size matches that of `float` as well.

Those two properties allow you to `bit_cast` between them.

Comment: Note that `struct X { unsigned char elems[5]; };` satisfies the rule you're citing. It can certainly be list-initialized with up to 4 elements. It can _also_ be list-initialized with 5 elements. I don't think any standard library implementer hates people enough to actually do this, but I think it's technically conformant.

Comment: Thanks! – Barry, I don't think that's quite right. The standard says: "can be list-initialized with up to N elements". My interpretation is that "up to" implies "no more than". Which means you can't do `elems[5]`. And at that point I can't see how you could end up with an aggregate where `sizeof(array<char, sizeof(T)>) != sizeof(T)`?

Comment: I believe the purpose of the rule ("an aggregate that can be list-initialized...") is to allow either `struct X { unsigned char c1, c2, c3, c4; };` or `struct X { unsigned char elems[4]; };` – so while the chars need to be the elements of that aggregate, this allows them to be either direct aggregate elements or elements of a single sub-aggregate.

Comment: @Timur "up to" does not imply "no more than". In the same way that the implication `P -> Q` does not imply anything about the case where `!P`

Comment: Even if the aggregate contains nothing but an array of exactly 4 elements, there's no guarantee that `array` itself won't have padding. Implementations of it may not have padding (and any implementations that do should be considered dysfunctional), but there's no guarantee that `array` itself will not.

Answer (score 13):

## The accepted answer is incorrect because it fails to consider alignment and padding issues.

Per [[array]/1-3](https://eel.is/c++draft/array):

> The header `<array>` defines a class template for storing fixed-size
>   sequences of objects. An array is a contiguous container. An instance
>   of `array<T, N>` stores `N` elements of type `T`, so that `size() == N` is an invariant.
>
> An array is an aggregate that can be list-initialized with up to `N`
>   elements whose types are convertible to `T`.
>
> An array meets all of the requirements of a container and of a
>   reversible container (`[container.requirements]`), except that a default
>   constructed array object is not empty and that swap does not have
>   constant complexity. An array meets some of the requirements of a
>   sequence container. Descriptions are provided here only for operations
>   on array that are not described in one of these tables and for
>   operations where there is additional semantic information.

The standard does not actually require `std::array` to have exactly one public data member of type `T[N]`, so in theory it is possible that `sizeof(To) != sizeof(From)` or `is_­trivially_­copyable_­v<To>`.

I will be surprised if this doesn't work in practice, though.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

According to the [paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0476r2.html) that describes the behaviour of `std::bit_cast`, and its [proposed implementation](https://github.com/jfbastien/bit_cast/blob/master/bit_cast.h) as far as both types have the same size and are trivially copyable the cast should be successful.

A simplified implementation of `std::bit_cast` should be something like:

```
template <class Dest, class Source>
inline Dest bit_cast(Source const &source) {
    static_assert(sizeof(Dest) == sizeof(Source));
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Dest>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Source>::value);

    Dest dest;
    std::memcpy(&dest, &source, sizeof(dest));
    return dest;
}
```

Since a float (4 bytes) and an array of `unsigned char` with `size_of(float)` respect all those asserts, the underlying `std::memcpy` will be carried out. Therefore, each element in the resulting array will be one consecutive byte of the float.

In order to prove this behaviour, I wrote a small example in Compiler Explorer that you can try here: https://godbolt.org/z/4G21zS. The float 5.0 is properly stored as an array of bytes (`Ox40a00000`) that corresponds to the hexadecimal representation of that float number in [Big Endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating_point).

Comment: Are you sure that `std::array` is guaranteed to not have padding bits etc.?

Comment: Unfortunately, the mere fact that some code works doesn't imply no UB in it. For example, we can write `auto bits = reinterpret_cast<std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(float)>&>(f)` and get exactly the same output. Does it prove anything?

Comment: @L.F. according to specification: `std::array` satisfies the requirements of [ContiguiosContainer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousContainer) _(since C++17)_.

Comment: @ManuelGil: `std::vector` also satisfies the same criteria and obviously cannot be used here. Is there something requiring that `std::array` hold the elements inside the class (in a field), preventing it from being a simple pointer to the inner array? (like in vector, which also has a size, which array does not require to have in a field)

Comment: @firda The aggregate requirement of `std::array` effectively requires it to store the elements inside, but I am worrying about layout problems.

Comment: @firda [\[array.overview\]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/array.overview#2)

Comment: @L.F.: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#def:aggregate - "no user-declared or inherited constructors" ... well, that sounds like a pretty big constraint, it cannot be anything else than wrapped array.

Comment: @firda I know, but we can still have layout issues.  https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class#bit-1

Comment: @L.F.: Still cannot see your point (other than that it could be over-aligned, possibly). If array is aggregate (no custom ctor) with list-initialisation, then it has to be array wrapper (or maybe recursive template like tuple - adding fields one by one). It cannot have any other field, so, `alignas` could mess things up? Or what do you suggest?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200653/discussion-between-firda-and-l-f).