# reinterpret_cast usage to manipulate bytes

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I was reading [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/byteswap) how to use the `byteswap` function. I don't understand why `bit_cast` is actually needed instead of using `reinterpret_cast` to `char*`. What I understand is that using this cast we are not violating the strict aliasing rule. I read that the second version below could be wrong because we access to unaligned memory. It could but at this point I'm a bit confused because if the access is UB due to unaligned memory, when is it possible to manipulate bytes with `reinterpret_cast`? According to the standard the cast should allow to access (read/write) the memory.

```
template<std::integral T>
constexpr T byteswap(T value) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>, 
                  "T may not have padding bits");
    auto value_representation = std::bit_cast<std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)>>(value);
    std::ranges::reverse(value_representation);
    return std::bit_cast<T>(value_representation);
}

template<std::integral T>
void byteswap(T& value) noexcept
{
    static_assert(std::has_unique_object_representations_v<T>, 
                  "T may not have padding bits");
    char* value_representation = reinterpret_cast<char*>(value);
    std::reverse(value_representation, value_representation+sizeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary reason is that `reinterpret_cast` can not be used in constant expression evaluation, while `std::bit_cast` can. And `std::byteswap` is specified to be `constexpr`.

If you added `constexpr` to the declaration in your implementation, it would be *ill-formed, no diagnostic required*, because there is no specialization of it that could be called as subexpression of a constant expression.

Without the `constexpr` it is not ill-formed, but cannot be called as subexpression of a constant expression, which `std::byteswap` is supposed to allow.

---

Furthermore, there is a defect in the standard:

The standard technically does not allow doing pointer arithmetic on the `reinterpret_cast<char*>(value)` pointer (and also doesn't really specify a meaning for reading and writing through such a pointer).

The intention is that the `char*` pointer should be a pointer into the object representation of the object, considered as an array of characters. But currently the standard just says that the `reinterpret_cast<char*>(value)` pointer still points to the original object, not its object representation. See [P1839](https://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1839r5.pdf) for a paper proposing to correct the specification to be more in line with the usual assumptions.

---

The implementation from cppreference is also making an assumption that might not be guaranteed to be true: Whether `std::array<std::byte, sizeof(T)>` is guaranteed to have the same size as `T`. Of course that should hold in practice and `std::bit_cast` will fail to compile if it doesn't.

If you want to read some discussion on whether or not it is guaranteed in theory, see the questions [std::bit_cast with std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320316/stdbit-cast-with-stdarray), [Is the size of std::array defined by standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103244/is-the-size-of-stdarray-defined-by-standard) and [What is the sizeof std::array<char, N>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25173462/what-is-the-sizeof-stdarraychar-n)

Comment: Constexpr-ness sounds like the real reason, and inability to do arithmetic on reinterpreted `char*` sounds like a standard defect.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I moved around the parts of the answer to make clear what the more relevant issue is.

Comment: I removed constexpr from the second version, you are right about constexpr-ness