# Cast pointers in consteval

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constexpr, compile-time, consteval

I wanted to make a compiletime data encryptor.
I tried this by creating a struct with a buffer, and a constructor for that struct that
would read an array of structures in that buffer. And because I wanted to use blockcypher,
I wanted that buffer length to be devideable by 16.

Here is my codesnippit:

```
    template <typename type, size_t len>
    struct DataPackage
    {
        unsigned char buffer[len * sizeof(type) + (16 - ((len * sizeof(type)) % 16))]; //create buffer to fit all types and fill to 16 byte blocks

        __forceinline consteval DataPackage(type data[len])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); i++)
                buffer[i] = i < len * sizeof(type) ? *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data) + i) : '\0';
        
            //encrypt buffer here
        }
    };
```

It gives me the error:
conversation from 'type*' to 'unsigned char*' is invalid in constant expression evaluation.

I use visual c++ compiler with c++ 20.

Is there a way to cast a pointer to a pointer to a different type in a consteval function?
Is there maybe a dirty compile hack workaround?
What exactly is preventing me from this, could this be fixed in future versions of c++?

Comment: Read this : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression.

Core constant expressions
A core constant expression is any expression whose evaluation would **not** evaluate any one of the following: 18. reinterpret_cast. So reinterpret cast is not allowed in consteval

Comment: @PepijnKramer and is there another way of casting a pointer without reinterpret_cast in consteval?

Comment: The backslashes are not necessary. It's just Markdown-style markup.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to reinterpret data as a different type in a constant expression, but you can cast the object representation to a different type if that is your intention:

```
auto obj_repr = std::bit_cast<std::array<unsigned char, sizeof(type)>>(data[i]);
```

Now `obj_repr` is an array of `unsigned char` containing the object representation of the `i`th element of the array. You can operate on that copy.

This requires of course that `T` is trivially-copyable. Otherwise your `reinterpret_cast` approach would have undefined behavior as well anyway. Furthermore to make this work as a constant expression `type` may not be or contain as subobject a pointer type, a union type, a pointer-to-member type, a `volatile`-qualified type or a reference type.

(There is some disagreement on whether theoretically this is always guaranteed to work because `std::array` may not be required to be free of padding, but it will work in practice. See e.g. [std::bit_cast with std::array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320316/stdbit-cast-with-stdarray.))

---

A `consteval` function can *only* be evaluated at compile-time. Therefore I highly doubt that `__forceinline` has any meaning on it, although of course that is purely implementation-defined and I don't know how MSVC handles it in this situation.

Usually `consteval` is not required over `constexpr`. I don't see anything in the code you are showing that needs to be prevented from being evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks you for clarifying Things!