# How to get a pointer to the bytes of a uint32_t

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a complete `uint32_t` using vector of `uint8_t` bytes. It should be filled iteratively. It can happen in any of the following ways:

- 1 byte and 3 bytes.
- 2 bytes and 2 bytes.
- 4 bytes.
- 3 bytes and 1 byte.

```
    uint32_t L = 0;
    uint32_t* LPtr = &L;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data1 = {0x1f, 0x23};
    memcpy(LPtr, data1.data(), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(0x231f, L);
```

Above works fine (first two bytes). But following is not (with the two sets of bytes).

```
    uint32_t L = 0;
    uint32_t* LPtr = &L;
    std::vector<uint8_t> data1 = {0x1f, 0x23};
    std::vector<uint8_t> data2 = {0x3a, 0xee};
    memcpy(LPtr, data1.data(), 2);
    memcpy(LPtr, data2.data(), 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(0x231f, L);
    EXPECT_EQ(0x231fee3a, L);
```

The issue I feel is `LPtr` does not point to the next byte that should be filled next. I tried `LPtr+2` which is not pointing to individual byte of `uint32_t`.

This should be done using `memcpy` and output should go to `uint32_t`. Any idea to get this sorted?

Endianness is not an issue as of now. It can be corrected once the `uint32_t` is completed (when eventually 4 bytes get copied).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char *>(LPtr) + 2, data1.data(), 2);`

Comment: The second call to `memcpy` overwrites the first data, because you pass the exact same destination pointer.

Comment: You may want using bit shifts instead of memcpy.

Comment: Have you looked up how your CPU stores data in memory? The bytes might not be in the order you expcect. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: Instead of memcpy have a look at std::copy, it is a bit more type safe. And will in practice compile to assembly that is at least as good as memcpy.

Comment: Even if you get the copy right, you still have the problem of endianess. In short, some architectures stores the low byte first in memory, others the high byte. By using arithmetics (shifts etc.) you can write code that runs on all architectures and typically is faster than code that use `memcpy`.

Comment: Bitcasting to an `std::array<std::byte, 4>` may also work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58320316/stdbit-cast-with-stdarray

Comment: So what is the problem? This is basic boolean algebra. For little endian CPU (Intel/AMD and ARM with Android and iOS) `uint32_t ret = (data[0] << 24) | (data[1]  << 16) | (data[2] <<8) | data[3];` for big endian CPU (i.e. PowePC, Ultra Spark) `uint32_t ret = (data[0] >> 24) | (data[1]  >> 16) | (data[2] >> 8) | data[3];`

Comment: P.S. About [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using a pointer to uint32_t so incrementing it won't make it iterate by 1 byte, only by 4 bytes. Here is a version which populates all bytes of L, but it's still messing with endianness:

```
uint32_t gimmeInteger(std::vector<uint8_t> data1, std::vector<uint8_t> data2)
{
  assert((data1.size() == 2));
  assert((data2.size() == 2));
  uint32_t L = 0;
  uint8_t* LPtr = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&L);
  memcpy(LPtr, data1.data(), 2);
  memcpy(LPtr+2, data2.data(), 2);
  return L;
}
```

Comment: One could mention that this is one of the few instances, where `reinterpret_cast` is used legally without aliasing trouble. (In general cases for unrelated types only possible for `std::byte`, `char` and `unsigned char` - `uint8_t` should be one of those - but e.g. not for `signed char`.) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast